# Remove elements from an array when get a match in another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays in javascript

**Array 1**

```
var columns=[{name: 'id', default: true}, {name: 'type', default: true},{name: 'typeName', default: true}, {name: 'client', default: false}];
```

**Array 2**

```
var unSelect=["id", "type", "typeName"]
```

Now I want a new array i.e `Array 3` where only non-matching element matches
i.e `name` of `column`

In this case

```
var array 3=[{name: 'client', default: false}]
```

I have tried to splice, but my index is not matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using **filter** as

```
var unSelect=["id", "type", "typeName"];
var array3 = columns.filter(function(obj){
  return unSelect.indexOf( obj.name ) == -1;
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var columns = [{
  name: 'id',
  default: true
}, {
  name: 'type',
  default: true
}, {
  name: 'typeName',
  default: true
}, {
  name: 'client',
  default: false
}];
var unSelect = ["id", "type", "typeName"];
var array3 = columns.filter(function(obj) {
  return unSelect.indexOf(obj.name) == -1;
});
console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest way to do it using `Array.prototype.map` function. This function can iterate an array and return what you want per every iteration.

```
var array3 = columns.map(function(item) {

   if (unselected.indexOf(item.name) < 0)   //see if the name of an element object is in the unselected array
     return item;                           // if yes, return the element 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table as a reference for not wanted item for faster access than `indexOf`.

```js
var columns = [{ name: 'id', default: true }, { name: 'type', default: true }, { name: 'typeName', default: true }, { name: 'client', default: false }],
    unSelect = ["id", "type", "typeName"],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result;

unSelect.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a] = true;
});

result = columns.filter(function (a) {
    return !hash[a.name];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution with `Array.prototype.filter()` & `Array.prototype.some()` combo.

```js
var columns = [{name: 'id', default: true}, {name: 'type', default: true},{name: 'typeName', default: true}, {name: 'client', default: false}],
   unSelect = ["id", "type", "typeName"],
   filtered = columns.filter(f => !unSelect.some(e => e == f.name));
console.log(filtered);
```